# File Not Found exception in C# and C

Tags: c#, c

I am facing problem while trying to open a simple text file in C#. What i tried so far includes:

- Change the location of file from C dir to D dir.
- Place file inside a folder
- Check its properties and its not read only
- Create new text file from scratch
- Code in C instead of C#

but all the above variations failed and i got the same exception "That file not found". I am not sure whats wrong there. Its might be some bug in windows 7 or may be some security feature of windows 7 which prevents file from being accessed inside code.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Edit:
Code in C

```
FILE *pFile;
    pFile = fopen("d:\\test\\series.txt", "r");

    if (pFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("File not found or Unable to open file\nPress any key to continue . . ." );
        getch();
        return;
    }   
    else
    {
      // do processing here
    }
```

C# Code:

```
string[] AllLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("D:\\test\\data.txt");
```

Comment: can you show code snippet that don't work

Comment: Does the file actually exist in the location you are attempting to open?  Are you escaping your backslashes in your path string?  Do you even have a valid path string to open the file in the right path?

Comment: No code, its not a real question.

Comment: @ abelenky Hi i have edited my question and show code along with that, i guess that there is no sense of posting fake question

Comment: By the way both of above code works fine on windows xp

Comment: In `C`, print the system message about the error. Add `perror("fopen");` or similar inside the `if (pFile == NULL)` block. Also I noticed the files in your `C` and `C#` examples are named different.

Comment: @Stecya I added code to my question

Comment: @Jeff Mercado I added the code and i guess i am not making any such mistake which you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible the path isn't right.  Check your file path string, use either the '@' prefix to make it literal, or escape your backslashes as Jeff M suggested.

```
var filename = @"C:\somedir\somefile.txt";
```

or

```
var filename = "c:\\somedir\\somefile.txt";
```

Comment: but this, of course, is a guess until we see the actual code.

Comment: You are doing nobody a favor by having guessed right.  This is going to be a horrid place if you teach users that posting sloppy questions is acceptable.

Comment: Aside from the bad wording (the `@` doesn't make a literal any more literal: all literals are already literal), your guess isn't even "likely": non-escaped bad quotes are more likely (on average) to crash the compiler due to a bad escape sequence than to get through, so if that where the issue we'd be replying to a quite different question.

Comment: You're right on pre-guessing, but I have had escape sequences before which do actually compile but fail at runtime. (of course, it happens to magically hit a true escape sequence like \n or \t, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You are likely looking at a permissions issue. Insure that the user context that the application is running under has read/write permissions to the directory you wish to access. Is this a web app?, if so then the web server operates under different credentials than your own, and that account may not have permission.

Cheers,

CEC

Comment: Complete guess! Need to see code and exception before you can jump to this conclusion. And it's quite a jump.

Comment: 1. I offered what I could with the information available, which is more than you did. Why are you whining about it?  
2. If I believe @Jame to not be looking for a file that doesn't exist, in a directory that doesn't exist, using a command that would otherwise open a file, permissions is not that far of a leap.